# jwnl unable to install database

Tags: java, wordnet, jwnl

I am trying to build a bespoke dictionary. I am testing with jwnl. I get the following error:

```
 net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Unable to install    
 net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary
```

My xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jwnl_properties language="en">
    <version publisher="Princeton" number="2.0" language="en"/>
    <dictionary class="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary">
            <param name="morphological_processor" value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.DefaultMorphologicalProcessor">
                    <param name="operations">
                            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupExceptionsOperation"/>
                            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.DetachSuffixesOperation">
                                    <param name="noun" value="|s=|ses=s|xes=x|zes=z|ches=ch|shes=sh|men=man|ies=y|"/>
                                    <param name="verb" value="|s=|ies=y|es=e|es=|ed=e|ed=|ing=e|ing=|"/>
                                    <param name="adjective" value="|er=|est=|er=e|est=e|"/>
                <param name="operations">
                    <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupIndexWordOperation"/>
                    <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupExceptionsOperation"/>
                </param>
                            </param>
                            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.TokenizerOperation">
                                    <param name="delimiters">
                                            <param value=" "/>
                                            <param value="-"/>
                                    </param>
                                    <param name="token_operations">
                    <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupIndexWordOperation"/>
                                            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupExceptionsOperation"/>
                                            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.DetachSuffixesOperation">
                                                    <param name="noun" value="|s=|ses=s|xes=x|zes=z|ches=ch|shes=sh|men=man|ies=y|"/>
                                                    <param name="verb" value="|s=|ies=y|es=e|es=|ed=e|ed=|ing=e|ing=|"/>
                                                    <param name="adjective" value="|er=|est=|er=e|est=e|"/>
                        <param name="operations">
                            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupIndexWordOperation"/>
                            <param value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.morph.LookupExceptionsOperation"/>
                        </param>
                                            </param>
                                    </param>
                            </param>
                    </param>
            </param>
            <param name="dictionary_element_factory" value="net.didion.jwnl.princeton.data.PrincetonWN17FileDictionaryElementFactory"/>
            <param name="file_manager" value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl">
                    <param name="file_type" value="net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile"/>
                    <param name="dictionary_path" value="/"/>
            </param>
    </dictionary>
    <resource class="PrincetonResource"/>
```

I have the following Java code -

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(page);
    try {
        JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream("file_properties.xml"));
        String s = doc.text();
        String[] words = s.split(" ");
        for (String word: words) {
            // check is word is in dictionary
            IndexWord aWordIndexNoun = Dictionary.getInstance().getIndexWord(POS.NOUN, word);
            IndexWord aWordIndexAdj = Dictionary.getInstance().getIndexWord(POS.ADJECTIVE, word);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("system found an error - " + e);

    }
```

I am using Java 1.7, under Ubuntu and using Eclipse for testing.
I assume the error is in dictionary_path but I cannot find anything that works. I did not manually download wordnet database - I am unsure where that is located. Does anyone have any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the answer is to install mysql but I have not tested that because my system uses mongo db.